# Parsing image from website, and outputting as links

Tags: php, html, dom

So I've been working on this project for some time now. I'm creating a website that displays my artwork. I do so by parsing images from my deviantArt gallery, and then passing those to links on my site, to use with Slimbox 2. The solution I've decided to use is to create a parser in PHP. The code below is my solution -

```
<?php
class Functions {
    public function getImageHref($url) {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $page = file_get_contents($url);

        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $dom -> loadHTML($page);
        $imgs = $dom -> getElementsByTagName('a');
        $hrefArray = array();

        foreach ($imgs as $a) {
            $class = $a -> getAttribute('class');

            if ($class === "thumb") {
                $hrefnode = $a -> getAttribute('href');
                $hrefArray[] = $hrefnode;
            }
        }
        return $hrefArray;
    }

    /*
     * @author - Matt Cain from www.caincode.com
     * (Edited to fit purpose)
     */
    public function scrapeLargestImage($array) {
        $linkArray = array();

        foreach ($array as $link) {
            // Returns the page content
            $page = file_get_contents($link);

            //Makes sure the page is not null
            if (!$page) {
                return false;
            }

            // Works with internal errors in libxml (basically hides those errors)
            libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

            /*Creates a new document, and loads it from the URL
             * Then returns all img elements */
            $dom = new DOMDocument;
            $dom -> loadHTML($page);
            $imgs = $dom -> getElementsByTagName('img');
            $imgsVisited = array();
            $maxLen = 0;
            $largest = '';

            // Iterates through each image on the page
            foreach ($imgs as $img) {

                //Returns the image attribute
                $src = $img -> getAttribute('src');

                //Checks if the image is null or has been visited
                if (!empty($src) && !isset($imgsVisited[$src])) {
                    $imgsVisited[$src] = true;
                    $ch = curl_init($src);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                    $data = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    if ($data === false) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    /* Sets image length to contentLen, then checks if
                     * contentLen is larger than the lax length*/
                    $contentLen = 0;
                    if (preg_match('/Content-Length: (\d+)/', $data, $matches)) {
                        $contentLen = (int)$matches[1];
                    }
                    if ($contentLen > $maxLen) {
                        $maxLen = $contentLen;
                        $largest = $src;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Checks if there is a largest image, returns it's src attribute if so
            if (!empty($largest)) {
                $linkArray[] = $link;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return $linkArray;
    }

    public function createLinks($array) {
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $numArray = array();
        $count = 1;

        foreach ($array as $link) {
            $count++;
            $a_text = 'image #' + $count;
            $a = $dom -> createElement('a', $a_text);

            $hrefAttribute = $dom -> createAttribute('href');
            $hrefAttribute -> value = $link;
            $a -> appendChild($hrefAttribute);

            $relAttribute = $dom -> createAttribute('rel');
            $relAttribute -> value = 'lightbox-gallery';
            $a -> appendChild($relAttribute);

            $dom -> appendChild($a);
        }
        echo $dom -> saveHTML();
    }

}
?>
```

And then I use it in my design.php file like so -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script src="javascript/jquery.1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="javascript/slimbox2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slimbox2.css" media="screen" />

        <title>Hathor's Website | Design</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header id ="header">
            <div id="header-content">
                <div class="logo"><a class="logo" href="index.html">*</a></div>
                <ul id="header-list">
                    <li><a class="inactive" href="index.html"><p class="active-text">Home</p></a></li>
                    <li><a id="active" href="design.php"><p class="active-text">Design</p></a></li>
                    <li><a class="inactive" href="code.html"><p class="active-text">Code</p></a></li>
                    <li><a class="inactive" href="youtube.html"><p class="active-text">Youtube</p></a></li>
                    <li><a class="inactive" href="about.html"><p class="active-text">About</p></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="main">
            <p class="intro">Take a look below at a gallery of my art!</p>
            <div id="test">
                <?php
                    include 'php/functions.php';
                    $functionsClass = new Functions;
                    $functionsClass->createLinks($functionsClass->scrapeLargestImage($functionsClass->getImageHref(http://hathorarts.deviantart.com/gallery/)));
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The output I get is this (on the site) - 
[image: Example Output]

However, I have configured my WAMP server correctly, because when I use the following codes - 
http://pastebin.com/9hy00NKv and then the HTML for it - http://pastebin.com/inLpPLQk
it works perfectly. 
What is my mistake, and how can I fix it?

Thanks for the future help!

Comment: If you post the actual contents of the `design.php` file, it will be easier to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: @AlfEaton The contents of it aren't relevant, because I set up that example file similar, where I use HTML in a PHP file, and only in one div do I use this PHP code. But if you think it would be more than just unnecessary code, I'll go ahead and post it.

Comment: The example given doesn't contain the text "Take a look below at a gallery of my art!", so it's impossible to know where the problem is.

Comment: @AlfEaton Edited with the full text in, but I'm fairly sure the problem is in the PHP. I'll have time to re-read it tonight, but I'm not really sure where the error would be.

Comment: I don't think that's the actual code of `design.php`, as it has a syntax error at line 34 (the URL needs single quotes around it).

Comment: @AlfEaton It's a direct copy-and-paste of my design.php file, to be honest. I did forget my single quotes, thanks. That was actually the problem, so I'll post my edited function.php file up there. It has a maximum execution time of 30 seconds now. Is there a better way to parse images from a website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XPath will make it easier to select elements from the page, and trying to reduce the number of fetched pages will make things much faster:

```
<?php

// fetch the index page
$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://hathorarts.deviantart.com/gallery/');
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

// select the linked thumbnail images
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//a[@class="thumb"]');

// get the URL of each large image and build image links
$output = new DOMDocument;
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
    $link = $output->createElement('a', 'image #' . $i);
    $link->setAttribute('href', $node->getAttribute('data-super-img'));
    $link->setAttribute('rel', 'lightbox-gallery');
    $output->appendChild($link);
}

print $output->saveHTML();
```

If you can cache the output, that would be a good idea, too.

Comment: Wow, this is beautiful code. I'll go back to the chopping block with learning PHP. Thanks mate!